# A sentence encoded as images

Tags: knowledge, cipher, visual

***Decode a meaningful sentence from this image full of images.***

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This puzzle refers to

> The NATO phonetic alphabet

> Reading from top to bottom then left to right we get

> The logo of **Papa** John's without the name -> **P**
>  The Greek letter **Alpha** -> **A**
>  **Charlie** Chaplin -> **C**
>  The magnitude denoted by the prefix **Kilo** -> **K**
>  **Mike** from Stranger Things -> **M**
>  The logo of the **Yankees** -> **Y**
>  Johnny **Bravo** -> **B**
>  An **Oscar** award -> **O**

> A chest **X-Ray** -> **X**
>  A bottle of **Whiskey** -> **W**
>  The flag of **India** -> **I**
>  People dancing a **Tango** -> **T**
>  The Grand Budapest **Hotel** from the film with the same name -> **H**
>  People dancing a **Foxtrott** -> **F**
>  The flag of **India** -> **I**
>  Writer **Victor** Hugo -> **V**

> An Amazon **Echo** -> **E**
>  The Greek letter **Delta** -> **D**
>  An **Oscar** award -> **O**
>  A still image from the movie **Zulu** -> **Z**
>  An Amazon **Echo** -> **E**
>  A calendar heading for the month of **November** -> **N**
>  Some **Lima** beans -> **L**
>  The flag of **India** -> **I**

> The flag of **Quebec** -> **Q**
>  Some kind of **Uniform** -> **U**
>  An **Oscar** award -> **O**
>  **Romeo** from the 1996 movie "Romeo and Juliet" -> **R**
>  **Juliet** from the 1996 movie "Romeo and Juliet" -> **J**
>  Some kind of **Uniform** -> **U**
>  A **Golf** club and ball -> **G**
>  The flag of **Sierra** Leone -> **S**

Putting the letters together we get the sentence

> **Pack my box with five dozen liquor jugs**, which is a pangram, a sentence that contains every letter in the English alphabet.